# How can I rotate an ndarray (image) properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I generate an image of random noise as shown below.

```
image_shape = (299, 299, 3)
image = np.random.uniform(size=image_shape) + 128.0
```

I need to rotate this image by small amounts (-25 to +25 degrees). I'm currently using [scipy.ndimage.rotate](http://lagrange.univ-lyon1.fr/docs/scipy/0.17.1/generated/scipy.ndimage.rotate.html) but it results in the image turning mostly white. Rotating the ndarray using np.rot90 works fine but I can't rotate the image like this since I need to only use small angles.

```
plot_image(image)
plot_image(np.rot90(image))
plot_image(rotate(image, 5))
```

The code above results in the following output:

[image]

Comment: The approach seems correct and if I use it, [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdYED.png) is created, which seems to be desired. Please make sure to have a clear problem description including a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: Not reproducible. On my machine it works fine.

Comment: your code works fine. please include your full code

Answer (score 2):

In the original question the line:

`image = np.random.uniform(size=image_shape) + 128.0`

creates an image with pixels values all between 128 and 129. The visualization then auto-scales the color map between these values. After rotation, pixels with 0 value appear in the corners. Auto-scale then maps the color scale between 0 and 129, thus giving the B&W aspect.

Answer (score 1):

I use opencv to do this, following code assumes you wish to rotate it around its center, clockwise:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def rotate(img, angle):
    img = cv2.imread(img)
    (height, width) = img.shape[:2]
    (cent_x, cent_y) = (width // 2, height // 2)

    mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cent_x, cent_y), -angle, 1.0)
    cos = np.abs(mat[0, 0])
    sin = np.abs(mat[0, 1])

    n_width = int((height * sin) + (width * cos))
    n_height = int((height * cos) + (width * sin))

    mat[0, 2] += (n_width / 2) - cent_x
    mat[1, 2] += (n_height / 2) - cent_y

    return cv2.warpAffine(img, mat, (n_width, n_height))
```

Lemme know if all works well!

PS: if you're interested in manipulating images from Python code, I strongly recommend you follow Adrian Rosebrock's blog.

Comment: So why would one prefer this lengthy solution instead of `scipy.ndimage.rotate(img, angle)`, which is a single line of code?

Comment: In my case it's because opencv is my go to library for almost all of my image manipulation projects, and I prefer to minimize dependencies. But also because the algorithm above enables you to compute the new width and height of the rotated image, ensuring no part of the image is cut off. ;) Now I haven't used scipy's implementation so does it do that?

Comment: I guess you might have misunderstood the question. It is about why `scipy.ndimage.rotate(img, angle)` is not working the way it should (however, it does for the general case and there is a lot of information missing, but that's not the point here). It is not about using a different technique. If the question is "Why does the engine of my BMW not start in the morning?", answering "You could take a Mercedes; here is how to get one: ..." is not actually helpful.

Comment: I have read the op several times, and it doesn't say anything about not wanting an alternative solution. Could be a misunderstanding on part tho.

Answer (score -1):

I would create a function that maps to each pixel from your input image a pixel to its corresponding rotated image.
Make sure you rotate with respect to the central pixel (if that's indeed the rotation you're looking for)

```
(rows, cols) = img.shape
mid_coords = np.floor(0.5*np.array(img.shape))

def rotate_pixel(pixel_coords, cos_angle, sin_angle):
    x = mid_coords[0] + (pixel_coords[0] - mid_coords[0]) * cos_angle
    y = mid_coords[1] + (pixel_coords[1] - mid_coords[1]) * sin_angle
    if 0<=x<rows and 0<=y<cols:
       return (x,y)
    else:
       return False

rotated_img = np.zeros((rows, cols))
cos_angle = np.cos(angle)
sin_angle = np.sin(angle)
for i in range(rows):
   for k in range(cols):
       coords = rotate_pixel((i,k), cos_angle, sin_angle)
       if(coords):
           rotated_img[coords] = img[i][k]
```